# What is autoware?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

stupid question, but not clear for me, in the context of ROS:

What is autoware ?

What is the relationship with ros ? I did not understand the hype (a lot of traffic) at ros discussion forum.

Thank for some hints :-)

Cheers
Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320323/what-is-autoware-?/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2019-04-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-04**:
Something for @Geoff?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-04-04**:
+1, the first this hit my radar was this year and there's been alot of movement From Geoff and others which has been fascinating to watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://www.autoware.org/

Autoware is a framework for self-driving built on top of ROS. You can think of it as the self-driving vehicle equivalent of something like MoveIt. While the current version is built on ROS 1, the next version is being built on ROS 2 with a much greater focus on things like safety, security and robustness.

I'm not sure I would call the increase in traffic on Discourse "hype". It's more that the traffic has moved there from elsewhere, mainly the GitHub issue tracker. The project has been around for quite a while.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2019-04-05**:
Hi Geoff,

**self-driving vehicle equivalent of something like MoveIt**

Million thanks to you, this will solve the knot in my brain :-)
I've noticed a lot of professional planing, management and work.

Sorry for the hype :-)

Cheers
Chrimo